# How to avoid loading this library upon each application start-up

Tags: youtube-javascript-api

I'm using https://apis.google.com/js/client.js library for initialization my application and for getting access to YouTube feeds. I must load this library each time on app start-up:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady"></script>
```

And after set key and load library:

```
function googleApiClientReady() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey('my_api_key');
    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function() { ... });
}
```

How to avoid loading this library upon each application start-up; download library and include it to project locally?

Comment: "How to avoid loading this library upon each application start-up" you can't unless you save the contents fo your library locally and serve it, but why use youtube if you want to save the files locally??  Can you explain the issue rather then a solution?

Comment: I develop the app for Watchface device, it is connected with smartphone via BT connection. Video can play with "medium" video quality, it plays normally. But each app start up I need to load and set up https://apis.google.com/js/client.js library. It takes ~8 seconds each time.